# Force reload of dirty/invalid model in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to build out edit functionality for a Goal record. On the Goal index page, there is an edit button next to each goal. When clicked, each field becomes editable. Upon clicking Save, the changes are saved to the server. So far so good.

There is also a Cancel button. When a user clicks it, I need to reset the state of the model to what it was before they changed things. `goal.rollback()` in the controller works fine for this. Except, if the user has already clicked Save but there were server side validation failures. In this case, attempting to rollback() throws `` Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `reloadRecord` on <App.Goal:ember123:1234> while in state root.loaded.updated.invalid. ``

If instead I try to `goal.reloadRecord` I get `` Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `reloadRecord` on <App.Goal:ember123:1234> while in state root.loaded.updated.invalid. ``

Same deal with `goal.unloadRecord`. I have tried massaging the state like this:

```
state = goal.get('currentState') #this code makes me sad.
state.isValid = true
state.isError = false
```

And like this:

```
goal.transitionTo('loaded.saved')
```

To no avail. Is make zero sense to me the reloading or unloading a record should be statefull.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Again, I'm trying to take a dirty, invalid record in ember and get it back to a happy state either by rolling back changes, or just reloading it from the server.

EDIT: Ember-data v1.0.0-beta.3-4-g169793e, ember Version: 1.1.2

Comment: rollback seems to be working after a save error for me, are you using Ember Data?  If so, which version?

Comment: Ember-data v1.0.0-beta.3-4-g169793e, ember Version: 1.1.2.

Comment: gotcha, I added a working example, is there some difference?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example, change the color then hit save.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/44/edit

PR submitted https://github.com/emberjs/data/pull/1590

Comment: Wow thanks! A separate cancelation function like this: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/49/edit?html,css,js is what I'm trying to accomplish, but that DOES work, so when I get back later this afternoon I will try to see what I'm doing differently in my code and come up with a jsbin demonstrating the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: Ok I figured out the difference. In the jsbin the model has state "root.loaded.updated.uncommitted" after update failure. In my code after update failure the model has state "root.loaded.updated.invalid".

I think the difference is in the http code the server is returning. In that case of the jsbin, it is 403. In the case of my application, it is 422. Indeed, when I have the server return 403, the model has state "root.loaded.updated.uncommitted", so a rollback works :)

Is this the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: which adapter are you using?

Comment: You're using the Active Model Adapter, the rest adapter works.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/55/edit

Comment: You can set isError on the record to true and then call rollback, this seems like a bug to me.  http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/56/edit

Comment: Yes I am using the AM Adapter. Should I not be? If it is a bug, any thoughts on a workaround?

Comment: this, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/56/edit seemed to work as a workaround.  I prefer the rest adapter, but i don't have a rails backend.  I'll look into the other adapter more